# Base64 encoded images not showing in IE

Tags: javascript, html, image, internet-explorer

I'm constructing html content server-side which consists of PNG images being converted to base64 string and then appended to a string using string builder. 
I have 200 images and for each image I am looping through each one and converting them. However when the content is being returned to the client the browser window only displays around 100 images and the rest are all blank. i.e. the red "X" is displayed as a place holder for the image.

Example

```
using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
     fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
     byte[] imgBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
     string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes);
     html.Append("<img src='data:image/png;base64," + base64String + "'/>");
}
```

It seems to only be a problem in IE 9 and works fine in Chrome. 
What could be causing this issue in IE, is it one of the IE settings?, maximum size?, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer has [limited support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (see the "Remarks" section) for the Data URI scheme, e.g:

- *For security reasons, data URIs are restricted to downloaded
  resources. Data URIs cannot be used for navigation, for scripting, or
  to populate frame or iframe elements.*
- *Data URIs cannot be larger than 32,768 characters.* <-- this might explain why some of the images are being displayed correctly.
- *The resource data must be properly encoded; otherwise, an error
  occurs and the resource is not loaded. The "#" and "%" characters
  must be encoded, as well as control characters, non-US ASCII
  characters, and multibyte characters.*

Comment: I've been doing some more testing and I'm always getting different resulst each time, its never the same cut off point. Sometimes theres more images loaded and sometimes theres less.

Comment: I've been searching for more information about the use of daat uri in IE and this 32k maximum only exists in IE 8 and for IE 9 the limit was raised to 4gb. But htis information was on blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/09/15/ie9-beta-minor-change-list.aspx. In wikipedia its states that IE 9 does not have a limit. But this cant be the issue as I'm getting different results each time and it works fine in Chrome